# PHP - If no results, wait and try again

Tags: php, sleep

I'm calling a web service via GET protocol and the response will either be echoed out on the page as true or false.

I'm trying to write logic that will retry up to 3 times if the web service returns false.  However, the first time I want to wait 1 second, the second time I want to wait 10 seconds, and the third time I want to wait 60 seconds.

This is what I currently have.  Is there a better way to achieve this?

```
if ($wsReturn == 'false') {
    sleep(1);
    $wsReturn = strip_tags(file_get_contents($link));

        if ($wsReturn == 'false') {
            sleep(10);
            $wsReturn = strip_tags(file_get_contents($link));

                if ($wsReturn == 'false') {
                    sleep(60);
                    $wsReturn = strip_tags(file_get_contents($link));
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: recursive function with counter is an alternative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an array and a loop to make any number of iterations with any pause times

```
$i = 0;
$sleep = [1, 10, 60];

while( $wsReturn == 'false' )
{
    sleep( $sleep[$i] );

    // your logic goes here
    $wsReturn = strip_tags(file_get_contents($link));


   if( ++$i >= count($sleep) )
      break;
}
```

Comment: Sidenote: `$sleep = [1, 10, 60];` will fail on PHP < 5.4

Comment: true, but you shouldn't use PHP < 5.4 in 2015 :)

Comment: I know. But we don't know which version they're using, *just saying* ;-)

Comment: Thank you.  Would we need { } around that break?  Also, do you not have to increment the $i after the logic line?  Does PHP auto increment $i variables in while loops?

Comment: Hey Will! We do increment $i in this line: `if( ++$i >= count($sleep) )`. It's not auto-incremented. The ++ operator does it for us, and **then** the comparison is evaluated. Braces are not required because it's only one line, but you can add those if you like.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up with after @Pavel Lint sparked the idea for me:

```
$i = 0;
$waitTimes = array();
$waitTimes = [1, 10, 30]

while ($wsReturn == 'false') {
    sleep( $waitTimes[$i] );
    $wsReturn = strip_tags(file_get_contents($link));
    $++i

    if ($i >= count($waitTimes)-1) { break; }
}
```